# Laravel 5.5 checkbox management and database update

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to create a setup which allows to setup a platfom and the first step consists on defining langs which will be used in the platform...

**For this i created 2 routes :**

```
Route::get('/home/setup', 'BackOffice\FirstconnectionController@initLang');
Route::patch('/home/setup', 'BackOffice\FirstconnectionController@initLangUpdate')->name('setup.setLang');
```

The first one call the initLang method which displays the list of langs which are trashed (i use softdeletes for this...). By default all languages have a timestamp in the deleted_at field.

```
public function initLang()
{
    $langs = Lang::onlyTrashed()->get();
    $sectorsCount = Sector::count();
    return view('admin.firstConnection', compact('langs', 'sectorsCount'));
}
```

**In my view :**

```
{!!  Form::model($langs, [
        'method' => 'PATCH',
        'route' => 'setup.setLang'
    ])  !!}
@foreach($langs as $lang)
   {!! Form::label($lang->langname,  $lang->langname ) !!}
   {!! Form::checkbox( 'lang[]', $lang->id ) !!}
@endforeach
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Finally the form is sent and i recover the data in the initLangUpdate() method**

```
public function initLangUpdate(Request $request) {
    $request = $request->input('lang');
    return $request;
}
```

My problem is the following :

- I get an array of string : ["3","4"] and i should have an array of integer
- How do i manage to make my update in my table ? In fact the update should be to set deleted_at to NULL
- Is there another way to get the datas : i recover the values with an array : lang[]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just did this :

```
foreach ($request as $entry) {
    Lang::withTrashed()->find($entry)->restore();
}
return redirect('admin/home/setup')->with('success', 'It works ...');
```